# Initializing a vector of vectors of objects

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I'm having trouble creating a vector of vectors of objects.
The goal is to get something like a chessboard, with each of the fields beeing an 
 object which can then be accessed by using the vector.

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class raster;

class field{
  int x, y;
public:
  field(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {};
  friend class raster;
};

class raster{
  const size_t s=12;
  vector<vector<field> > game_row(s,vector<field>game_column(s,0)); //here I get the second error
public:
  friend class field;
};
```

So I want the vector of vectors to be a member of a different class, but each time I compile using g++ it says
error: 's' is not a type
error: expected ',' or '...' before '(' token

Sorry if i mixed up the formatting of the post,
I'm pretty new to c++ and this is my first post here.

Comment: `0` cannot initialize `field`...

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
class raster{
  const static size_t s=12;
  vector<vector<field> > game_row{s,vector<field>(s,field(0,0))}; //here I get the second error
public:
  friend class field;
};
```

1. `t` should be static
2. use initailize expression, so that the compiler would not recognize the expression as a function declare expression

Comment: This doesn't compile. You can't name the vector inside the vector. Remove `game_column`. You also can't initialize a `field` with 0.

Comment: @super yes, it's a mistake, fixed

Comment: @MichaelWalz fixed now

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues in that one line of code:

```
vector<vector<field> > game_row(s,vector<field>game_column(s,0));
```

First - what is `game_column`? It looks like you are trying to declare the vector elements as a named variable; that's not how it works. I think you should remove `game_column` altogether.

Then, you have the issue that the declaration for `game_row` looks like a function declaration, not a variable declaration. (Confusingly, C++ allows the syntax you have used to declare variables, but not immediately inside class declarations - only in other contexts such as inside functions!).

You can use an alternative syntax such as:

```
vector<vector<field>> game_row {s,vector<field>(s,0)}; // C++11 +
```

or for C++98, you need to add an explicit constructor and initialise the data members in the initialiser list:

```
    size_t s;
    vector<vector<field> > game_row;
public:
    raster() : s(12), game_row(s, vector<field>(s,0)) { }
```

(From here I'm going to assume you're using C++11).

However, this change will still yield an error; you cannot initialise a `field` object with just a single `int`, since you specified that its constructor requires a pair of `int` values. Therefore, you need:

```
vector<vector<field>> game_row {s,vector<field>(s,{0,0})};
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped alot! I didn't get the idea of having one name for the vector at first, but now I do! Code works now.